# Add floats in list

Tags: python-3.6

I have a list as below, I want to add only floats from below string and `'Test'` should be ignored.

```
create_list = ['268.159189729643', '241.2704253641898', '261.97011777877833', '255.7887557077164', '289.9109120496156', 'Test']
```

Please let me know how it can be achieved ?

I tried as below, but I get below error:

```
for v in create_list:
    if float(v):
        sum_power = sum_power + float(v)
    else:
        next
```

The error encountered is:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'None'

Edited:

I now have below code and it seems to be working fine. Is there a better way of writing the same piece of code ?

```
for v in create_list:
    try:
        sum_power = sum_power + float(v)
    except ValueError:
        logging.info(v + " Not a float")
```

Comment: I added the code which I tried..

Answer (score 0):

You should replace:

```
if float(v):
```

with:

```
if isinstance(v, float):
```

to avoid the ValueError.